# Detecting blank/empty function in cpython calls?

Tags: python, optimization, cpython

We have an application that allows users to override optional python callback functions.

Example when serial data is received, an optional user-defined python function is called:

```
def onDataReceived(bytes, timeStamp, address, peer):
    return
```

This is not from a source file, but compiled in the app.

Note that the application is a real-time processing engine in C++ so any calls to the cpython interpreter consumes quite a bit of overhead.  I do have access to the precompiled functions so is there any way to determine if its trivially blank/empty as above without resorting to hand parsing the text directly?

Thanks.

Comment: @msw Confused why the question is impossible to answer. Antti Haapala has given a very workable solution below.

Comment: So calls into the interpreter are ok? Your question suggests otherwise.

Comment: I can make calls to the interpreter and cache the results as the code is compiled in the app as mentioned, so its trivial to detect when a textual edit has been made.  I just don't want to invoke the final function repeatedly unnecessarily afterwards.

I can also take his answer and examine the CPython equivalent PyFunctionObject, directly as I'm currently implementing now.

Do not feel the question still merits the down vote in light of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the `func.__code__.co_code` (Python 3; on Python 2 use `func_code` instead of `co_code`). This is a byte string containing the function's byte code.

Thus:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return
... 
>>> def bar():
...     pass
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> foo.__code__.co_code
b'd\x00\x00S'
```

So you can create a function that compares the `__code__.co_code` against a known empty function:

```
def empty():
    pass

empty_code = empty.__code__.co_code

def is_empty(func):
    return hasattr(func, '__code__') and func.__code__.co_code == empty_code
```

Note that functions that have a docstring, have slightly different bytecode (the docstring takes up a constant slot), and so forth. For more sophisticated ones you can inspect the byte-code disassembler output output.

Comment: Thanks very much.
Might there be a case when func does not contain a __code__ attribute?

Comment: @rbairos if it is an object with `__call__` or a builtin/C function for example, or bound method.